# Vagrant Shell Provisioning runs but fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vagrant

I have a simple vagrant box that I am building while working through a tutorial. I have built on the box here is my vagrant file.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"

  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080



end
```

This seems to work fine and is waiting for some other configuration but the problem I am having with the provisioning.

It finds the Shell script fine with no errors. It even builds the vagrant box. However when it finishes I get this error

```
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: bash: /tmp/vagrant-shell: /user/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
bash: /tmp/vagrant-shell: /user/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I ssh in nothing I setup to install is installed. When I run the bash script in the terminal command by command it works. Here is my bash script.

```
#!/user/bin/env bash

#install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wget php5 apache2 php5-mcrypt php5-curl git
sudo apt-get update

#apache onfig
sudo a2enmod rewrite

#Symlink for local development
#remove the WWW for Apache
sudo rm -rf /var/www

#symlink for local directory ln -fs {PATH TO LOCAL PROJECT} /var/www
sudo ln -fs /pathtolocaldirectory /var/www

#Restart Apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is quite clear actually: `/user/bin/env` does not exist.

Simply replace the first line in your bash script by:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: This was it I changed the environment to

#!/bin/bash

and that sorted the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What @AaronBlakeley wrote was the solution for me under Windows 8.1 - replace the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` with `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Your /tmp directory or script itself is missing permission and that might be the root cause of this execution issue.

To Solve this , try

```
chmod 755 /tmp/

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell
```

And then try to execute the command, it will work safe.